# Different permissions for same type of post

Tags: taxonomy, permissions

I am building a website that has a bunch of pages and two post pages:

1. News
2. What's New

Both of these pages will be like category pages. **How can I allow one set of users to only create content for the What's New section?**

For example:

- One set of users can only create content for What's New
- One set of users can only create content for News

How can I enforce a rule like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to create two custom post types. One will be "news" and one will be "whats-new".

So for example, you could create a plugin in `/wp-content/plugins/` called `news-post-types.php`. The code below will create special permissions that only apply to this post type:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Post types and permissions for News and What's New
*/
// on init, create a custom post type called News
add_action('init', 'wpse_create_post_types');
function wpse_create_post_types() {
    // Capabilities: this is how you'll enable some users to edit, delete, etc.
    $capabilities = array(
        'edit_post'                 => 'edit_news',
        'read_post'                 => 'read_news',
        'delete_post'               => 'delete_news',
        'create_posts'              => 'create_news',
        'delete_posts'              => 'delete_news',
        'delete_others_posts'       => 'delete_others_news',
        'delete_private_posts'      => 'delete_private_news',
        'delete_published_posts'    => 'delete_published_news',
        'edit_posts'                => 'edit_news',
        'edit_others_posts'         => 'edit_others_news',
        'edit_private_posts'        => 'edit_private_news',
        'edit_published_posts'      => 'edit_published_news',
        'publish_posts'             => 'publish_news',
        'read_private_posts'        => 'read_private_news'
    );
    // Other CPT arguments
    $args = array(
        // Important: make sure to include the next 2 args for capabilities
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'capabilities' => $capabilities,
        // You can adjust the other args as needed
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'page-attributes')
    );
    // Actually create the post type
    register_post_type('news', $args);
}
```

As long as you specify `has_archive` as true when you register the custom post type, you will also automatically get a category-like page for each one, without having to create any custom templates.

Make sure to activate your plugin and also visit the Settings > Permalinks page. You don't need to change anything there, but this will flush your rewrite rules so the new URLs will worok.

So now, you have a custom post type with custom capabilities. You need to do at least one more thing: create a role that has these permissions. Right now, none of your users (even Admins) have access - that's because you have just created custom capabilities that aren't automatically mapped to any users.

In the same plugin file:

```
// 'news_author' is a slug, 'News Author' is how you will see this role in wp-admin
add_role('news_author', 'News Author', array(
    // You may or may not want to give them all these capabilities.
    // For example you could let them publish but not delete.
    'delete_news' => true,
    'create_news' => true,
    'delete_news' => true,
    'delete_others_news' => true,
    'delete_private_news' => true,
    'delete_published_news' => true,
    'edit_news' => true,
    'edit_others_news' => true,
    'edit_private_news' => true,
    'edit_published_news' => true,
    'publish_news' => true,
    'read_private_news' => true,
    // If you want them to be able to upload files and read on the front end,
    // make sure to include the following 2 capabilities:
    'read' => true,
    'upload_files' => true
));
```

Finally, you may also want to have Admins (like yourself perhaps) be able to add/edit/delete these custom News posts. If so, add this to the plugin:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'wpse_add_admin_caps');
function wpse_add_admin_caps() {
    $role = get_role('administrator');
    $role->add_cap('delete_news');
    $role->add_cap('create_news');
    $role->add_cap('delete_news');
    $role->add_cap('delete_others_news');
    $role->add_cap('delete_private_news');
    $role->add_cap('delete_published_news');
    $role->add_cap('edit_news');
    $role->add_cap('edit_others_news');
    $role->add_cap('edit_private_news');
    $role->add_cap('edit_published_news');
    $role->add_cap('publish_news');
    $role->add_cap('read_private_news');
}
```

You can do the same thing for your "What's New" section - create a second custom post type, then add a role for it, then optionally add those capabilities to the administrator role as well.

Comment: A very detailed answer. Thank you.